# Laravel and MySQL Dates - Translation to UTC from GMT

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date

I have an app which have to manage 2 kind of dates:

- Normal dates which can be formatted with PHP function set timezone and then shown in the client timezone.
- I have a table with each hour in every one of the 7 days of a week, showing if a worker is enabled for working at this day/hour. This table is set in GMT+0. When a user enters the app I have to show this day/hour table translated to their timezone.

For doing this I have set a select in the register with the GMT timezones with an offset. In this way I take an array and change the hours with this GMT offset.

The issue comes when I try to use PHP timezone set function, it uses UTC so the GMT timezone is irrelevant. If I ask for UTC timezone to the user on register, I dont have a offset to translate the day/hours table.

So what I need to find is an approach to use one of them (UTC or GMT) or even a way to translate between them the offsets.

**EDIT:**
Translating hours function

```
public static function convertCalendarConfigToTimeZone($timezone_id, $psico_id){
    $timezone = Timezone::find($timezone_id);
    $configs = User::find($psico_id)->calendar_configs;
    $hours_array = [
      array("day"=>"0", "configs"=>array()),
      array("day"=>"1", "configs"=>array()),
      array("day"=>"2", "configs"=>array()),
      array("day"=>"3", "configs"=>array()),
      array("day"=>"4", "configs"=>array()),
      array("day"=>"5", "configs"=>array()),
      array("day"=>"6", "configs"=>array()),
    ];
    foreach($configs as $diaHora){
      $newhour = $diaHora->hour+$timezone->offset;
      $newday = $diaHora->day;
      if($newhour<0){
        $newhour = 24 - $newhour; 
      }
      if($newhour>$diaHora->hour){
        $diaHora->day = $diaHora->day-1; 
      }
      if($diaHora->day<0){
        $diaHora->day = 6;
      }
      if($diaHora->day>6){
        $diaHora->day = 0;
      }
      if($diaHora->enabled){
        $aux = ["hour"=>$newhour, "enabled"=>true];
      }else{
        $aux = ["hour"=>$newhour, "enabled"=>false];
      }
      array_push($hours_array[$newday]["configs"], $aux);
    }

    return $hours_array;
  }
```

This is one of the functions I use to translate a calendar configuration using GMT

This is the table:

```
id          int(10)
user_id     int(10)
day         int(11)
hour        int(11)
enabled     tinyint(1)
created_at  timestamp
updated_at  timestamp
```

Example data in the table:

```
id  user_id day hour    enabled created_at          updated_at
169 3       0   0       0       2016-07-14 09:17:32 2016-10-17 19:07:34
170 3       0   1       0       2016-07-14 09:17:33 2016-10-17 17:51:06
171 3       0   2       0       2016-07-14 09:17:33 2016-10-18 09:37:38
172 3       0   3       0       2016-07-14 09:17:33 2016-10-17 19:11:40
173 3       0   4       0       2016-07-14 09:17:33 2016-10-17 19:12:40
174 3       0   5       0       2016-07-14 09:17:33 2016-10-17 19:12:40
and more for each day/hour...
```

As I previously said I save the timezone for the user on the registration form. And use it in this functions to translate in an array. But If I use this method to translate the array I cannot use PHP timezones cause they are UTC not GMT.

Comment: Laravel comes with [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) which makes dealing with dates much easier. The `setLocale()` method may be of interest to you.

Comment: I know Carbon, but I have 2 types of dates, I can use carbon for the first, but still can do nothing with the second if I use carbon.

Comment: OK, could you add some code so I can see what you are trying to do?

Comment: I will add some code (cant put all cause of it is so large), but it is not a solution, only what I had achieved.

Comment: That's fine, just some code to show the problem. I know your explanation makes perfect sense to you, but to us it's difficult to understand as we are not working on your project.

Comment: There is no difference in utc and gmt https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=GMT&oq=GMT&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=GMT+vs+utc

Comment: So, If I cand find a relation of timezones like Europe\Madrid and his offsets I could save in my DB and all woud be solved